# Using a javax.usb.properties file in OSGi bundle

Tags: usb, osgi

I'm trying to access an USB device from an OSGi container. I am using `javax.usb`, with usb4java as its underlying implementation. I have converted all relevant JAR files to OSGi bundles by modifing their `MANIFEST.MF` files. This works ok, where finding classes is concerned.

[I need to tell javax.usb what implementation is used](http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/faq.html#what_is_properties_file) by specifying a `javax.usb.properties` file on the classpath. Problem is: the classpath is seperate for each bundle. How do I put the properties file on the classpath of the javax.usb bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the classpath of a bundle using a [Bundle fragment](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Fragment):

> Sometimes, fragments are used to 'patch' existing bundles:
>
> Host bundle:
>
> ```
> Bundle-SymbolicName: the.host
> Bundle-ClassPath: patch.jar,.
> ```
>
> Fragment:
>
> ```
> Bundle-SymbolicName: the.host.fragment
> Fragment-Host: the.host
> ```
>
> In this scenario, the patch.jar is not available in the host bundle
>   itself, but may be supplied by the fragment. Since it is ahead of '.'
>   it will allow classes to be preferentially loaded from the fragment
>   instead of the host.